# hadoop copyFromLocal error on Amazon AMI

Tags: hadoop

Hi I am using clustertogo-base-v004 (ami-53a8263a) on amazon to do some experiment
and when I issue the following command.

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /ncdc/sample.txt hdfs://localhost/tmp/sample2x.txt

I got the following error:

copyFromLocal: Call From ip-10-31-153-189.ec2.internal/10.31.153.189 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

reading the wiki and this message.
It can be the IP is wrong or the  service is not starting running.
I got an elastic IP set up but it is not using that IP

any help..

Comment: What happens if you don't specify the scheme or host?  `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /ncdc/sample.txt /tmp/sample2x.txt`